# Python app made with py2app doesn't work

Tags: python, macos, pygame, py2app

I want to make a game called "dodgeball". I have a main script, a setup.py script and an image called ball.bmp. In my setup.py script I have the following code:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['dodgeball.py']
DATA_FILES = ["ball.bmp"]
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

When I run

```
sudo python setup.py py2app
```

Everything goes perfectly, except when I try to open Dodgeball.app it gives me this error (In a pop-up error window):

dodgeball Error

Open Console
Terminate

And it only works in alias mode:

```
sudo python setup.py py2app -A
```

How should I fix this?

I'm on Mac OS X El Capitan (10.11). I'm aware the new Mac update broke a few stuff.

Answer (score -2):

import pygame._view worked.

:D